# Joint Distribution of Dependent Uniform Distributions

Tags: probability

The question is as follows:

Let $X \sim U(0,1)$ and conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ be $U(0,x)$

I believe that the joint density of X and Y can be expressed as follows by the definition

$p(x,y) = p_{y|x}(y|x)p_x(x) = \frac{1}{x} \mathbf{1}_{(0,x)}(y) * \mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$

How does one find the density of Y (I'm not sure how to integrate $p(x,y)$)

the conditional density of X given Y=y, and E[X|y=y]?

I know that E[X] = 1/2 and E[Y] should be 1/4 but I'm also not sure how to write the equation for the latter

Comment: Plotting the support of the joint density helps in setting up the right integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_Y(y)=\int_y^{1} \frac  1  x dx=-\ln y$ for $0<y<1$.

[$0<y<x$ forces $x>y$, so you have to integrate w.r.t. $x$ from $y$ to $1$].